# how to point shm object to an other shm object

Tags: c++, object, memory, pointers, shared

Hi I've learned that if I have a shared memory (c++) class object then it makes no sense to add member variables which are poiners if this pointer would be used in unrelated processes to access the same thing. But how is it then possible to make linked lists inside a shared memory. Say one shm object points to an other shm object. Is this not possible to acheive in a way that any unrelated process could iterate through the chain inside shm. If it is possible, then how?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found that you can measure the distance between two structures in SHM by for example knowing the exact size of the structures involved. So if you place it at an arbitrary distance preferably page aligned, you can just add the distance to the start pointer returned by mmap and that would point to the second, third etc.
example:

```
items[i].start = (void*)((char*)items[0].start + calcoffset)
```